# SEToolkit: havester not capturing credentials

Tags: social-engineering, credentials

I am using the Setoolkit on Ubuntu. I am testing it by cloning Facebook and logging myself in locally to see if I capture my own credentials. However,no POSTS are written to the harvester text file that SET creates to capture credentials. I have tried moving the files around and changing permissions, but nothing works. I can view the cloned site on my machine. Any ideas what the issue could be ?

Comment: Check the post.php file, maybe it's not copying the post data.